# How to resolve Azure Active Directory IDX10500: Signature validation failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, azure-active-directory

We are using Azure B2C Active Directory and attempting to integrate with C# WebApi with OWIN security middleware. I have a native app which allows me to acquire a token successfully from the AD which I then place in a Bearer header and use it in a subsequent webapi call.

I'm running the service locally on my development machine at the moment and have followed online examples for enabling OAuthBearerAuthentication as follows:

```
var jwtFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(settings.MetadataEndpoint));

        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // This SecurityTokenProvider fetches the Azure AD B2C metadata & signing keys from the OpenIDConnect metadata endpoint
            AccessTokenFormat = jwtFormat
        });
```

I can see that my call is attempting to be validated (locally running remember) which leaves me with the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException' occurred in System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
```

Remembering that I have not got any certificates set up of my own, and the tokens that should be used for validation should presumably be validated by the OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider which gets metadata from the AAD instance.

What do I do to make this work locally? Is this a problem with it running locally at all?

Edit: This is the code taken from Github examples that uses the OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider:

```
public class OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider : IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider
{
    private readonly ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> _configManager;
    private string _issuer;
    private IEnumerable<SecurityToken> _tokens;
    private readonly string _metadataEndpoint;

    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _synclock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(string metadataEndpoint)
    {
        _metadataEndpoint = metadataEndpoint;
        _configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(metadataEndpoint);

        RetrieveMetadata();
    }

    public string Issuer
    {
        get
        {
            RetrieveMetadata();
            _synclock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return _issuer;
            }
            finally
            {
                _synclock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SecurityToken> SecurityTokens
    {
        get
        {
            RetrieveMetadata();
            _synclock.EnterReadLock();
            try
            {
                return _tokens;
            }
            finally
            {
                _synclock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }

    private void RetrieveMetadata()
    {
        _synclock.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
            var config = _configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
            _issuer = config.Issuer;
            _tokens = config.SigningTokens;
        }
        finally
        {
            _synclock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

It is this class that is responsible for getting the tokens from the metadata endpoint in Azure B2C. Note that we haven't named these, they come provided from the B2C endpoint.

Comment: What's your SecurityKeyIdentifier? Pls provide the code related to it.

Comment: @Lily_user4045 I've added the security token provider which retrieves the tokens - as you can see we don't personally name these tokens, they come from B2C itself.

Comment: Hi, your error is Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier, I dont know  what about SecurityKeyIdentifier, is it a variable you define? Yes, native app dont need access token. B2C app should have Policy id in web config and set it properly.

Comment: I am also having the same issue, it all of a sudden just started happening and I can't figure out why.  I see ResolveIssuerSigningKey() failing, returning null for a token.  Happens even when I omit the bearer token stuff and just leave the UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication() for logging in interactively through the web app.

Comment: Ok, I knew if I posted that I would figure out my problem.  At one point I was unable to use ?p={policyname} in the MetadataAddress of the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions because then the URL was malformed (somewhere the middleware was adding another ?param=xx) so I then added the parameter in the RedirectToIdentityProvider notification, but SOMEWHERE in the OWIN mess actually uses the untouched MetadataAddress which was causing the security keys not being able to be resolved.  I had to go back to setting MetadataAddress using the ?p={policy} which solved the problem.